# Always Is (Past, Present, and/or Future?)

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, conjunctions, ambiguity

Is is the present simple tense of be.  But since the present tense is temporary instantaneous time period, what does "always is" mean?  I am not saying "is always" because: I am using always to be an adverb to is, so "is always" wouldn't make sense.

(Maybe there is a word other than always that makes this un-paradoxical?)

Comment: Your statement that the present tense can only be used for temporary things or for instants of time is self-evident nonsense.  On the contrary, it's often used to describe long-lasting or permanent situations or truths.

Comment: @rjpondI I don't disagree, but wouldn't that be grammatically incorrect.  Since is is the present tense of be?  I might be misunderstanding the meaning of the present tense.

Comment: Ah, you see, the problem is the terminology we use.  The fact that our uses of the tense don't fit the terminology is a problem with the terminology, not with our usage.  The present tense can refer to all-time truths, regular events ("I go there every Thursday") or future time ("I fly there next week").  The past tense can refer to hypotheticals that have nothing to do with the past ("if I saw him I'd ask about it"). Unfortunately these misleading terms are well established and unlikely to change any time soon. The "present participle" is one of the worst. It's used for past, present, future.

Comment: @rjpond does that mean that I should use always being instead?  Since that would satisfy both the terminology and usage.